# Can a Varnish director be queried for the number of healthy backends it contains?

Tags: load-balancing, varnish

Specifically in Varnish 3, is there a way to check  if a director has any healthy backends?

My use case is that I have a load balancer that is distributing traffic to 2 varnish boxes, which in turn are sitting in front of several web servers. I want Varnish to return a 200 to the load balancer's health check if the director has at least one healthy backend, without depending on passing the request through to an actual backend.

I'm looking for something like:

```
if (req.url ~ "healthcheck.html") {
    if (my_director.has_healthy_backend) {
        return 200
    } else {
        error 500 "No backends available"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main thing is that you have your director set up with probing, so it actually has a health status on your backends. If that is the case, then you could just use something like the following:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "healthcheck.html") {
        if (!req.backend.healthy) {
            error 503 "No backends available";
        } else {
            error 200 "All is well";
        }
    }
    [...rest of your logic...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent Varnish 4 solution is:

```
if (req.url ~ "healthcheck.html") {
  if (!std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    return (synth (503, "No backends available"));
  }
  else {
    return (synth (200, "All is well"));
  }
}
```